# Tool to get fonts used in afp file

Tags: afp

Does anyone know how can we get the fonts used in an Afp file .

I have tried Afp explorer , but it's not helping.

Please provide some suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2):

Use afpviewer tool
http://www.compulsivecode.com/project_afpviewer.aspx

- Open your AFP in above tool.
- Goto File option.
- Goto Extract resources option.
  It will list you all the resources include fonts, overlays and PSEG's etc. If your resources are embeded, you'' be able to extarct them also.

We write C Program to list or extract any resource from AFP.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one:
[Extract_Afp_Resources](http://www.zensys.com/downloads/extract_afp_resources_exe.zip)

```
USAGE:

extract_afp_resources.exe -i input_file [-o output_file] [-r resource_dir] [-l] [-v] 

Explanation of options:

-i     input_file The input AFP file from which to extract resources
-o     output_file Output AFP created without resources. This argument is optional.
-r     resource_dir Directory into which resources are to be extracted.
-l     List mode. Inline resources are listed but not extracted.
-v     Verbose mode
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried using this. It gave me resources which didn't had any fonts information.

Comment: I've not understood: you need the font resources or you wish to know which fonts are used (arial, helvetica, ...)?

Comment: I need the fonts which are used , not the font resources.

Comment: If you just want to know which fonts are used then -l option is for you. If you want the font files then -r extracts them.

Comment: I tried using -l option , it gave me the list of resources not the fonts which are used.

Comment: we use different words: what do you mean when you say that you need the fonts? What do you expect?

Comment: ok, and what do you get? please look at this http://www.afpdriver.com/AFP_Font_Mapping_Table.txt

Comment: Sorry for late response , I got list having RES00001, RES00002,...RES00015 . It's not matching with any values given in the link you provided.

Comment: then you have to extract them and dump. You'll find something similar to FND Font Descriptor [80] 
                Typeface Description      :  "ARIALMT

Comment: for more info please look into: Font   Object   Content   Architecture Reference

Answer (score 0):

TallPine provides an AFP evluation tool call PageMapper https://tallpine.com/products/afp-developer-tools/. This tool lets you look at an XML version of the AFP file in a multitude of ways. You can extract your resources as well.

There are some other ways that might be easier by pulling them from the libraries from where the AFP is generated/spooled.